# I want to make a second animation after the first with kivy abd MDLabel

Tags: python, animation, kivy

So i created 2 labels and animated the first, but i cant make the second animation work i want to animate the labels2 right after the labels with the same animation attributes

```
Class DemoApp(MDApp):  
    def build(self,*args):
             labels= MDLabel(text = 'Welcome',halign = 'center',theme_text_color ='Custom', text_color = (0,0,0,1),font_style ='H4')
             labels2 = MDLabel(text='Welcome to Eden', halign='center', theme_text_color='Custom',text_color=(0, 0, 0, 1), font_style='H4')


             anim = Animation(opacity=0, duration=0)
             anim += Animation(opacity=1, duration=4)
             anim += Animation(opacity=0, duration=2)
             anim.start(labels)
             return labels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `on_complete` method of animation of the first label to start the animation for the second like below:

```
Class DemoApp(MDApp):  
    def build(self,*args):
             labels= MDLabel(text = 'Welcome',halign = 'center',theme_text_color ='Custom', text_color = (0,0,0,1),font_style ='H4')
             labels2 = MDLabel(text='Welcome to Eden', halign='center', theme_text_color='Custom',text_color=(0, 0, 0, 1), font_style='H4')


             anim = Animation(opacity=0, duration=0)
             anim += Animation(opacity=1, duration=4)
             anim += Animation(opacity=0, duration=2)
             def _cmp(*args):
                 anim2 = Animation(opacity=0, duration=0)
                 anim2 += Animation(opacity=1, duration=4)
                 anim2 += Animation(opacity=0, duration=2)
                 anim2.start(labels2)
             anim.bind(on_complete=_cmp)
             anim.start(labels)
             return labels
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! it plays only the first animation unfortunately, maybe that return is causing the problem at the end?

Comment: May be. Can you please explain what exactly you want to do with two labels? Is it just to vary the text attribute? In that case you don't need to define the second label. Instead you can do that in the ```on_complete``` method by the statement like ```labels.text = 'Welcome Eden'```.

Comment: It worked with only one label and i put labels.text = 'welcome Eden' on the first line of _cmp , thank you for the help!